# Specify image dimensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

I'm looking for a way using the [filepicker-rails](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails) gem to specify the image size. For example I would like to make it so my users cannot upload an image smaller than say 400 x 600 pixels.

Reading the [docs](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#pick) I can only find the max file size in bytes, nothing about dimensions. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For now FilePicker API doesn't provide a feature of limiting files' sizes by dimensions (only by bytes as you have already mentioned).

What you could do is check the dimensions' of files and if they are lower than desired (400x600 in your case) then convert them to this minimum size using FilePicker's [conversion feature](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#convert).

Comment: Could you explain how to check the dimensions exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker's new API has an option `Image Dimensions` where you can specify the height and width. With this local images with be upscaled or downscaled before the upload begins.

https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file-ingestion/javascript-api/pick

Answer (score -1):

Please check the [specs](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails/blob/master/spec/helpers/form_helper_spec.rb) and you-ll find out how to use the max_size :)

Comment: I mentioned this in my question `max_size` only does the size in bytes, I need dimensions.